# Part of HTML page in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview, asihttprequest

I'm trying to open part of html page with help of ASIHttpRequest and NSRange, but it isn't working.
My code:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSLog(@"Loaded");
    NSString *htmlString = [request responseString];
    NSString *string = @"<a>";
    NSRange range = [htmlString rangeOfString:string];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range.length += range.location;
        range.location = 0;

        string = @"</a>";
        NSRange rangeOpen = [htmlString rangeOfString:string options:NSBackwardsSearch range:range];
        if (rangeOpen.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            range.length -= rangeOpen.location;
            range.location = rangeOpen.location;
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
            NSLog(@"Range %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
            NSLog(@"%@", htmlString);
        }
    }
}
```

It was code for removing tags and I want to transform it. For example: I want to open text between  tags in UILabel or UITextView

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your delegate on that ASIHTTPRequest to the object where your range checking code lives?

The method you're trying to use is a delegate method, and I can see it declared in the checked-in GitHub repository.

https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h